# Is there a way to override the CallbackPath to include the scheme?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, google-oauth-.net-client

Using OAuth 2.0, we have our app set up to use Google as an external login and it all worked fine until something changed on Google's end and it's now complaining that:

> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

I think the problem here is that while we have the `redirect_url` set in the Google console to `https://ourwebsite.com/signin-google`, our server is behind a load balancer and the connection between the load balancer and the actual server(s) is `http` (since it's entirely an internal network) with the load balancer providing `https` to the external world. This didn't cause a problem before, but it seems it now doesn't work.

So it seems Google is seeing the `redirect_url` as `http://ourwebsite.com/signin-google` and rejecting it. We tried to force it to send the `redirect_url` with `https` as the scheme like this:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = googleKey,              
    ClientSecret = googleSecret,       
    CallbackPath = new PathString(@"https://ourwebsite.com/signin-google")
});
```

But this will complain because:

`The path must start with a '/' followed by one or more characters.`

In other words, you can't put a fully qualified path there. So is there any way to alter the `redirect_url` before it gets sent to google to correct the scheme?

Here's a screenshot from of the Google error showing that Google is seeing the `redirect_uri` as being `http`

[image]

**Update:**

I tried adding this to `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```

And, surprisingly, it gets me past the Google authentication error. Unfortunately, I then get redirected to `https:///ourwebsite.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied` and I'm not sure exactly why. I suspect it some kind of mismatch perhaps in the token that is returned because it's for `https` and the backend is still comparing it to `http`? Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't think Google can see that you use HTTP inside your private network. You probably don't comply with some of their [OAuth2 policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies).

Comment: @JánHalaša: It's not that Google can see we are using HTTP, it's that asp.net is telling it we are. See the screenshot I've added. Because the server is communicating (with the load balancer) over HTTP, the middleware is sending a redirect_uri with the HTTP scheme instead of HTTPS.

Comment: I don't know .NET much, but why is the server communicating with the load balancer? I would expect the load balancer to be used just for incoming requests - from clients to server.